# Using ShapeDrawable class in xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I created my own `ShapeDrawable`:

```
public class ShapeDrawablePlus extends ShapeDrawable {
   ...
}
```

And can easily use it programmatically:

```
 ShapeDrawablePlus sd = new ShapeDrawablePlus(rs, bgColor, color, stroke, strokes);
 btn.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);
```

Also, we can make same things in xml (if we created **shape_drawable_plus.xml** drawable in **/drawable** directory) and set it in layout like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/shape_drawable_plus"
```

But, is it possible to use my ShapeDrawablePlus class in xml layout and set some attr to it?

Comment: not directly,  you can do it by implementing LayoutInflater.Factory[2] interface

Comment: When implementing onCreateView you can use `LayoutInflater.createView()` method

Comment: also, when using a custom xml Drawable resource you will most likely need tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" attribute